# ConcurrentHashMap of <String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue> pairs not consistently registering additions

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap, javaagents

**Background**

I have a program, which by use of a Java agent and ASM, adds to a static `ConcurrentHashMap` containing `ConcurrentLinkedQueues` of `Object` arrays (termed as `ThreadMarker`s in the below snippets). The map's keys are thread ids and its values are queues of `ThreadMarker`s. Each queue is added to with every new `LINENUMBER` bytecode instruction encountered in a given .class file, where the thread that encountered the line uses its `id` attribute to identify which queue to add to, in the map.

**Code**
(Note, `QueueMapMediator`'s map's queues needn't be `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`s - they are each only accessed by a single thread).

```
public class QueueMapMediator {

    private static final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadMarker>> queueMap;

    private static final int CAPACITY;

    private static final ConcurrentStack<ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadMarker>> queueStack;

    static {
        CAPACITY = 16; // arbitrary limit - may be assigned any power of 2
        queueMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(CAPACITY << 4, 0.75f, CAPACITY << 4);
        queueStack = new ConcurrentStack<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < CAPACITY; i++) {
            queueStack.push(new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>());
        }
    }
    /**
     * Instantiation disallowed
     */
    private QueueMapMediator() {
    }

    private static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadMarker> newQueue(String id) {
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadMarker> q = queueStack.pop();
        queueMap.put(id, q);
        return q;
    }

    /**
     * Used by java agent to get map entry pertaining to
     * currently executing thread.
     *
     * @param id    Thread id stored as a key in queueMap
     * @return      value associated with key of value id
     */
    public static ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadMarker> getByThreadId(String id) {
        ConcurrentLinkedQueue<ThreadMarker> q = queueMap.get(id);
        return q != null ? q : newQueue(id);
    }

    public static String[][] output() {
        return queueMap.entrySet().stream()
                .map(m -> m.getValue().stream().map(e -> new String[]{
                                String.valueOf(e.getElements()[0]),
                                String.valueOf(e.getElements()[1]),
                                String.valueOf(e.getElements()[2]),
                                m.getKey()})
                        .toArray(String[][]::new))
                .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                .sorted(QueueMapMediator::compareThreadNanos)
                .toArray(String[][]::new);
    }

    /**
     * @param curr      A String array containing ThreadMarker information
     * @param other     A String array containing ThreadMarker information
     * @return          int result of comparison
     */
    private static int compareThreadNanos(String[] curr, String[] other) {
        long time1 = Long.parseLong(curr[0]);
        long time2 = Long.parseLong(other[0]);
        return Long.compare(time1, time2);
    }

    public static void printOutput() {
        for (String[] arr : output()) {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }

}
```

```
public class Agent {

    static final long START_TIME = System.nanoTime();

    public static void premain(String args, Instrumentation instrumentation) {
        instrumentation.addTransformer((new ClassFileTransformer() {
            @Override
            public byte[] transform(ClassLoader loader, String className, Class<?> classBeingRedefined, ProtectionDomain protectionDomain, byte[] classfileBuffer) throws IllegalClassFormatException {
                if (loader == null) { // bootstrap loader caught by this check - will not load user's code
                    return null;
                }

                if (className.startsWith("application/")) {
                    return classfileBuffer;
                }

                ClassNode cn = new ClassNode(ASM9);
                ClassReader cr1 = new ClassReader(classfileBuffer);
                cr1.accept(cn, 0);

                for (MethodNode mn : cn.methods) {
                    InsnList insns = mn.instructions;

                    if (insns.size() == 0) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    int lineNum = -1;
                    int l1 = -1;
                    int l2 = -1;
                    AbstractInsnNode node;
                    int numAdded;
                    for (int i = 0; i < insns.size(); i++) {
                        node = insns.get(i);
                        if (node instanceof LineNumberNode) {
                            lineNum = ((LineNumberNode) node).line;
                        } else if (node instanceof LabelNode) {
                            if (l1 == -1) {
                                l1 = i;
                            } else {
                                l2 = i;
                            }
                        } else if (node instanceof FrameNode) {
                            l1 = i;
                        }

                        if (lineNum > -1 && l1 < l2) {
                            InsnList addedInsns = new InsnList();
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/Thread",
                                    "currentThread", "()Ljava/lang/Thread;", false));
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL, "java/lang/Thread",
                                    "getId", "()J", false));
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/String",
                                    "valueOf", "(J)Ljava/lang/String;", false));
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, "application/QueueMapMediator",
                                    "getByThreadId",
                                    "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue;",
                                    false));
                            addedInsns.add(new TypeInsnNode(NEW, "application/ThreadMarker"));
                            addedInsns.add(new InsnNode(DUP));
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESTATIC, "java/lang/System",
                                    "nanoTime", "()J", false));
                            addedInsns.add(new LdcInsnNode(START_TIME));
                            addedInsns.add(new InsnNode(LSUB));
                            addedInsns.add(new IntInsnNode(BIPUSH, lineNum));
                            addedInsns.add(new LdcInsnNode(className));
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKESPECIAL, "application/ThreadMarker",
                                    "<init>", "(JILjava/lang/String;)V"));
                            addedInsns.add(new MethodInsnNode(INVOKEVIRTUAL,
                                    "java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue",
                                    "add", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z", false));
                            addedInsns.add(new InsnNode(POP));

                            numAdded = addedInsns.size();
                            insns.insert(insns.get(l1), addedInsns);
                            lineNum = -1;

                            i += numAdded - 1; // -1 to counteract i incrementing with next iteration
                            l1 = -1;
                            l2 = -1;
                        }

                    }

                }

                ClassWriter cw1 = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
                cn.accept(cw1);
                return cw1.toByteArray();

            }

        }));

    }

}
```

```
/**
 * @param <E>   type contained in Stack
 * @author      Brian Goetz and Tim Peierls
 */
public class ConcurrentStack <E> {
    AtomicReference<Node<E>> top = new AtomicReference<>();
    public void push(E item) {
        Node<E> newHead = new Node<E>(item);
        Node<E> oldHead;
        do {
            oldHead = top.get();
            newHead.next = oldHead;
        } while (!top.compareAndSet(oldHead, newHead));
    }
    public E pop() {
        Node<E> oldHead;
        Node<E> newHead;
        do {
            oldHead = top.get();
            if (oldHead == null)
                return null;
            newHead = oldHead.next;
        } while (!top.compareAndSet(oldHead, newHead));
        return oldHead.item;
    }
    private static class Node <E> {
        public final E item;
        public Node<E> next;
        public Node(E item) {
            this.item = item;
        }
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I'm generally getting the expected output (i.e. as many entries per thread as there should be, given the number of source lines they respectively encounter), however occasionally - usually first time running after some time - some entries are missing.

**Example**

If I have the following simple multithreaded program:

```
1  package test.usercode;
2 
3  import application.QueueMapMediator;
4
5  public class BasicMultithreadedPrinting {
6
7      public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
8          for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
9              Thread th = new Thread(() -> {
10                 System.out.println("Hello");
11                 System.out.println("Hello again");
12                 System.out.println("Hello once more");
13             });
14             th.start();
15         }
16         QueueMapMediator.printOutput(); // included to view result of instrumentation
17     }
18 }
```

If I instrument it using the above agent, I might get the following unexpected output:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello again
Hello again
Hello once more
Hello again
Hello once more
Hello once more
[44959100, 8, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45050000, 9, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45701600, 14, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45762500, 8, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45767300, 9, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45776400, 14, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45813400, 8, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45817400, 9, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45825400, 14, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45862800, 8, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45866700, 9, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45868500, 16, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 1]
[45892200, 10, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 23]
[45938500, 11, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 23]
[46329900, 11, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 25]
[46500300, 12, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 23]
[46656400, 12, test/usercode/BasicMultithreadedPrinting, 25]
```

...where one of the spawned threads doesn't register at all and another with `id` 25, only registered 2 of 3 lines it encountered. I have since tried adding strategically placed `print` lines to work out where the fault is occurring, but, I haven't been able to reproduce the issue yet.

Thanks in advance to anyone who makes it through this rather long question. I've included a fair amount of code in the hope that it yields more meaningful suggestions. I've included the `javaagents` tag on the off-chance the agent has something to do with the issue described and I'm not seeing it.

Comment: What’s the point of this `ConcurrentStack` class? There’s already `ConcurrentLinkedDeque` provided by Java. But why maintaining this stack of queues at all, instead of just creating a new queue for a thread when needed? Then, your program won’t crash when encountering more than 16 threads but just do its work. Besides that, you start threads but don’t wait for their completion. So it’s not surprising that some of them didn’t perform the intended action(s) yet when you print the recorded data.

Comment: So when do you perform `printOutput()` and how do you ensure that it does not happen concurrently to the other operations?

Answer (score 1):

If `getByThreadId` is called by different threads the use of overlapping get-put will fail and lose one of the values. It's better to replace with atomic action to ensure all one queue per entry:

```
queueMap.computeIfAbsent(id, k -> new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>() /* or queueStack.pop() */);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - atomicity was along the lines I was thinking, although, I wasn't aware of `computeIfAbsent` before you suggested it. Your answer would also explain why those queues containing only a partial account of the pertaining thread's encountered lines (e.g. thread with id 25 in question example) only seem to be missing the first entry/entries (and not the latter). I wonder though why it works as expected after the occasional initial hiccup.

Comment: Hmm, having said that, I implemented this change and ran into the same issue as before.

Comment: Generally, atomicity for such an operation is preferable. But as long as each thread has a unique key, there is no race condition.